# Add multiple rows to an OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet on mac

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

What is up with both `Excel` and `Calc` with adding multiple rows on Mac? In both cases the `Insert|Rows`  simply adds ***one*** row - without any option to enter a `count` of rows to add.

[image]

So what are we supposed to do here to add say 50 rows at one time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mark the number of rows you want to insert and then execute Insert > Rows.
All the rows you marked become new empty rows.

Depending on the knowledge before: "To mark" means: clicking the number of the row on the left side, go down with mouse to the final row and release the mouse button.

Comment: y this works.  Now the issue I had was I am a keyboardist. I really want to *type* the number of new rows. This approach here is somewhat lame .. but probably the only one available.